# Airflow schedule interval change

Tags: python, cron, airflow, airflow-scheduler

a simple question:

Is it possible to change the schedule interval of a Dag after definition automatically via Api or CLI?

Example: write a simple script that is scheduled every day and sets the schedule interval of the DAG every day by what ever conditions.

Is there a programmatically way to trigger DAGs at a specifc point in time? These time points change every day so for example:

There is a DAG called **DAG-Test**.

2020-01-01 -- run **DAG-Test** at   16:00 
2020-01-02 -- run **DAG-Test** at   19:00 
2020-01-03 -- run **DAG-Test** at   12:00 
...

Comment: Why do you want to change the interval?

Comment: To achieve a dynamic interval, that is changing due to unknown events, which are not known at the time of dag definition.

Comment: To achieve a schedule not covered by cron like mechanism

Comment: Sounds like you might want a sensor to hold off your tasks until some criteria is met?

Comment: I mean, there has to be a way, to define scheduled intervals dynamically, which means setting the trigger of a DAG to a specific time during the day. The holding off is a option (in case you do not have thousands of different intervals to revoke).

Comment: Can you explain _why_ they need to change?

Comment: sure, as you could think of an event driven schedule:  in the morning there was a database update announced, due to ongoing work in the backend, the database should be renewed 2 hours after the announcment. Which could be always a different point in time, according to the event.

Comment: Can you write a query which can indicate whether that event has completed or is still pending? Usually you don't change the schedule so often and instead use a sensor to wait until prerequisites are available.

Comment: but if I have defined a query for that, I need to schedule the DAG, is this possible?

Comment: Set the `schedule_interval` to the earliest (_or a bit after, to avoid retrys_) the prerequisites would be available then have the first task be a sensor which checks if the prerequisite is available and, once it is the process will move forward.

Comment: But there is my point, I am asking if this process of move forward is possible and how? Therfore I need to change the DAG schedule interval